# Не получается парсить цену лекарств

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, request

Не получается парсить информацию о стоимости товара https://www.eapteka.ru/
Можете помочь пожалуйста.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = "https://www.eapteka.ru/search/?sort=price&order=asc&q=%D0%90%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Ищем все элементы с ценой
    price_elements = soup.find_all('span', class_='listing-card__price-new')

    if price_elements:
        for price_element in price_elements:
            price = price_element.get_text(strip=True)
            print("Цена:", price)
    else:
        print("Цены не найдены.")
else:
    print("Ошибка при получении страницы:", response.status_code)

time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде, решил твою проблему.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = "https://www.eapteka.ru/search/?sort=price&order=asc&q=%D0%90%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0"

firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.headless = True  
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(10)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

# Ищем все элементы с ценой
price_elements = soup.find_all('span', class_='listing-card__price-new')

if price_elements:
    for price_element in price_elements:
        price = price_element.get_text(strip=True)
        print("Цена:", price)
else:
    print("Цены не найдены.")

driver.quit()  # Закрываем браузер
```

Если у тебя firefox, то устанавливаешь `pip install selenium geckodriver_autoinstaller`, если chrome, то `pip install selenium chromedriver_autoinstaller` и меняешь строчку `from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options` на `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options`